# Errors in regex code in python

Tags: python, regex

Im working on a homework assignment, I need to use regex's to find various, characters and strings in another larger string called lorem_ipsum, I keep getting TypeError: expected string or buffer, it is specified that lorem_ipsum is a string not a list so that's not the problem.
These are the two peices of code I've written:
this one is to find all non alphanumeric characters in lorem_ipsum, and output the number of times they occur, it should return 144:

```
string1 = len(lorem_ipsum)
pattern = "^[[]]"
matches1 = re.match(pattern, string1)
results = matches1.read()
```

this one is to find all the occurences of sit ament in lorem_ipsum, and output how many times they occur, it should output 3:

```
string1 = len(lorem_ipsum)
pattern = "sit[-:]amet"
matches1 = re.findall(pattern, string1)
results = matches1.count(pattern, string1)

print (results)
```

I've never had this problem before and as far as I can tell I've used the same syntax that worked for my previous assignments.

Comment: It may be more clear if you present us with samples and their expected output. Try using `[][]` for the first pattern instead (assuming you're trying to match `[` or `]`).

Comment: You should match a string, not a len. Here `len(lorem_ipsum))`.

Comment: i just tried [] [] and it didn't work, i will edit in the expected output

Comment: Why are you matching an int (the len)

Comment: I just changed that i will edit that in

Comment: @t.hill do you know what len() does?

Comment: yes of course in know what len() does it was suggested i use len() for this  by my assignment guidelines

Comment: `len()` returns a number. You pass that number to some `re` functions that expect a string or a buffer. A number is not a string or buffer, thus the error.

Comment: @t.hill len gives you the length of the string as an integer, you don't want len at all anywhere in your code as far as I know unless your'e measuring hte length of the list of matches

Comment: Please read my answer

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the `len()` around `lorem_ipsum` in line 2 of your code.

`len()` will give you the length of a string as an integer, which I don't think is what you want to be matching considering regex only takes a string or buffer. Remove the len so line 2 looks like this:

`matches1 = re.match(pattern, lorem_ipsum)`

Comment: Now that you've edited your code, you will be removing the len in line one